# image rotation with translation in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

i want to move the image from left to right which keep on rotating and it's size keep on decreasing until the image vanishes.
it want to do this in javascript for titanium.
i'd tried but the image jumps spontanously,then move down and then change the position but the movement is not smooth.
i just want that it may not jump.i'm not an experienced programmer so need your help.
i'm sharing some code here.

```
var tr_start = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix();
tr_start = tr_start.rotate(30);

var tr_end = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix();
tr_end = tr_end.scale(1);
tr_end = tr_end.translate(10,0);
tr_end = tr_end.scale(.5);
tr_end = tr_end.translate(20,0);
tr_end = tr_end.rotate(360);
tr_end = tr_end.translate(100,0);
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
    width:'30%',
    height:'30%',
    transform:tr_start,
}); 
var headerimg = Titanium.UI.createImageView({     
    backgroundImage:'header.png',
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%',
    zIndex:2   
});
view.add(headerimg); 
win.add(view);
view.animate({
    transform:tr_end,
    repeat:0,
    //autoreverse:true,
    duration:1000,
    curve:Titanium.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_IN_OUT
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set auto reverse to false it might help.